# How to get string (multi word) between characters

Tags: string, lua, character

Hello I am trying to get a string between two parentheses

```
str = "Reason = Failed to connect ( Nickname: Mc Gee ), Banned by: Andrew"
```

I want to only get *Nickname: Mc Gee*

I have looked everywhere but all the answers I have seen are for single worded strings and don't work with ()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`%b` pattern](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) that allows to specify brackets you want to match:

```
str = "Reason = Failed to connect ( Nickname: Mc Gee ), Banned by: Andrew"
print(str:match("%b()"):gsub("[()]","")) -- prints ` Nickname: Mc Gee `
```

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
str = "Reason = Failed to connect ( Nickname: Mc Gee ), Banned by: Andrew"
print(str:match("%((.-)%)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complicated answer:

```
local str = "Reason = Failed to connect ( Nickname: Mc Gee ), Banned by: Andrew"
print(string.match(str, "Reason = [%a%s]+%([%a%s]+:%s+(.*)%s+%).*"))
-- Mc Gee
```

Hope it's useful~